Angular multiple projects can not resolve relative path and baseUrl not working
i have this tsconfig.json in the project folder
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@fuse": ["./projects/ui/src/@fuse"],
        },
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}

and in my projects/ui folder i have the following tsconfig.app.config
tsconfig.config and tsconfig.app.config are not in the same folder!!!
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
        "types": [],
    },
    "files": ["src/main.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

The "paths" config for @fuse is not working. Fuse has a index.ts file so /* is not needed, but it is not working. Any ideas?
The other problem is in main.ts which is located in projects/ui/src/app/main.ts relative paths are not found. I tried to add in tsconfig.app.ts baseUrl: './src' but this is not working.
maint.ts:
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from 'app/app.config';

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));


Could you please share the structure of your project or app folder?

If you struggled to create a project directory, then you can use this one for creating the structure: https://rohityadav.info/guide/project-tree
